# The p tag content exceeding column width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a row. Inside the row , there is a class named `.col-md-6`.
Inside the column, I have a paragraph tag with some text.
The problem is that, the content of the paragraph tag is exceeding the column width.But I want the paragraph tag content to align itself properly in the column as shown in image.
Code:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-6">
        <p>TextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextTextText</p>
    </div>   
</div>
```

Link:
http://jsbin.com/zimuwonoyu/edit?html,output

I want it to be like the one as shown in image:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a CSS property for this.

```
p {
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! It Works!!

Answer (score 1):

CSS Property:

```css
p {
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```